# Не знаю, что делать с ошибкой EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python-3.x, input, subprocess

есть два скрипта. Первый, который находится в автозагрузке, активирует виртуальное окружение и запускает второй скрипт:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd PRG2\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd scripts\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"activate.bat\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"python assistant.py\n")
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

второй скрипт должен узнавать, что ввел пользователь и реагировать на это:

```
import time
import subprocess
import pyttsx3
from waiter import run
engine = pyttsx3.init()
ru_voice_id = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_RU-RU_IRINA_11.0'
engine.setProperty('voice', ru_voice_id)
print('begin')
engine.say('добро пожаловать, создатель')
engine.say('Жду ваших указаний!')
engine.runAndWait()
choice = input()
if choice == 'run':
    run()
```

по отдельности скрипты работают исправно, однако когда запускаешь всё выдается такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assistant.py", line 12, in <module>
    choice = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Образец коммуникации через PIPE.

**start.py**

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'assistant.py'],
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print('Enter choice.')
choice = input()
choice = '{}\n'.format(choice).encode()
print('Entered.')
result = proc.communicate(choice)
print(result)
proc.wait()
```

**assistant.py**

```
print('Started.')
choice = input()
print('>>', choice)
```

А вообще, если программам нужно "общаться", то стоит смотреть на сокеты.

Comment: однако, если этой строки не будет, всё равно ничего не работает. Или же как его заново открыть?

Comment: как решить саму проблему?